# Use MSBuild to build multiple solutions and copy the applications to separate folders

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, console-application

I have about 80 console applications that I want to build and output to separate target directories under a holding directory.

```
c:\builds
  /App1
  /App2
  /app3
```

This script does the mass build, but I cannot seem to get it to either copy the finished output from the release directory to the target directory, nor to send the output there directly.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="./**/*.sln"> 
            <Properties>Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU</Properties>
    </Solution>
    <MyReleaseFiles Include=".\bin\release\*.*" Exclude=".\bin\release\*vshost.exe" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <MyReleaseOutput>.\release</MyReleaseOutput>
        <OutputPath>c:\builds\$(AssemblyName)\</OutputPath>
        <OutDir>$(OutputPath)</OutDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(Solution)" BuildInParallel="true" Targets="Build" />
        <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyReleaseFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
    </Target>

 </Project>
```

Comment: That OutputPath has to be set in the project which gets build, only there it can evaluate $(AssemblyName) in the context of the project. Similar questions have been asked, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191467/msbuild-solution-command-line-output-to-individual-folders and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442883/use-solutionname-in-the-msbuild-commandline-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use MSBuild to build multiple solutions and copy the applications to separate folders

Just as stijn said "*That OutputPath has to be set in the project which gets build, only there it can evaluate $(AssemblyName) in the context of the project.*", so we could not use it out of project file directly.

As a workaround, you can use `ItemGroup` with `Subfolder` for each project:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Projects Include="project1.csproj" />
      <Subfolder>project1</Subfolder>
    <Projects Include="project2.csproj" />
      <Subfolder>project2</Subfolder>
    <Projects Include="project3.csproj" >
      <Subfolder>project3</Subfolder>
    </Projects>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then use `%(Projects.Subfolder)` for each OutputPath:

```
  <Target Name="_BuildSingleConfiguration">

    <MSBuild Projects="@(Projects)"
             BuildInParallel="true"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);OutputPath=%(Projects.BuildOutputPath)\%(Projects.Subfolder)" />
  </Target>
```

Certified:[How to give a different OutputPath per project per build configuration with MSBuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758003/how-to-give-a-different-outputpath-per-project-per-build-configuration-with-msbu)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Leo.  Clearly, I am approaching this somewhat askew in my thinking.  Given an app folder containing n sub-folders, each containing a solution, I was to build all of the solutions, and copy their output to a staging folder that I designate in the moment.  It sounds like I have to know what those n subfolders are at the time that I write the script. When in reality, the set or sub-set that I am working against may vary.  IOW, I cannot do what I want to do.